# Get raw query generated by sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Good afternoon everyone. I am developing a node.js/express system using sequelize.js (postgresql).

My problem is: I need to store the raw queries generated by sequelize in a log history, but I can't find a function that returns the generated query. Does anyone know if sequelize provides a function that returns the generated SQL query, or if there's any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best bet is to use Sequelize's built-in logging functionality.

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'username', 'pwd', {

  // you can either write to console
  logging: console.log

  // or write your own custom logging function
  logging: function (str) {
    // do stuff with the sql str
  }
});
```

Comment: what if I want to print specific query only and not all queries?

Comment: You can use {logging: true} with the particular query. Check the params of the [FindAll](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll)

Comment: What if we only want to get a query not to execute?