# Get raw query generated by sequelize.js as a string

Tags: sequelize.js

I need to get the sql query generated by a `findAll` call, preferably synchronously (w/o promise). It's not for logging purpose and i don't want it for all queries, just for one specific query so setting a logger [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951836/1823497) won't help.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a specific log function to a single query. You probably can do whatever you need in it synchronously.

try something like:

```
//sample log function
function notOnlyALogger(msg){
   console.log('hey, Im a single log');
   //do whatever you need in here
   console.log(msg);
}

//using the logger only when needed
MyModel.findall({where:{foo:'bar'}, logging: notOnlyALogger });
```

and you should be fine.